# Formatting a DateDifference string

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, date-and-time

I have code like

```
startTime = DateString[];
...
endTime = DateString[];
timeElapsed = 
  DateDifference[startTime, endTime, {"Hour", "Minute", "Second"}];
```

Then ToString[timeElapsed, OutputForm] prints something like

```
0 hours 0 minutes 4. seconds
```

I would like to re-format this as

```
0h 0m 4.s
```

So I tried

```
ToString[timeElapsed, OutputForm] /. {" hours" -> "h", " minutes" -> "m"}
```

but this just gives back the same output as if I had made no replacements.

How can I make this string replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use may use either [`QuantityForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityForm.html) or [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html).

```
startTime = Now;
endTime = DatePlus[startTime, {4, "Seconds"}];
timeElapsed = DateDifference[startTime, endTime, {"Hour", "Minute", "Second"}];
```

Then

```
ToString@QuantityForm[timeElapsed, "Abbreviation"]
```

> ```
> 0 h 0 min 4. s
> ```

or

```
StringReplace[{" hours" -> "h", " minutes" -> "m", " seconds" -> "s"}]@ToString[timeElapsed]
```

> ```
> 0h 0m 4.s
> ```

Hope this helps